# Unable to install virtualenvwrapper on mac

Tags: python, django, macos, terminal, virtualenv

I am trying to run Django on python 3.6.1 according to this [website](http://www.marinamele.com/2014/07/install-python3-on-mac-os-x-and-use-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper.html). So i first installed virtualenv using

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

But this gives me an error:

```
copying build/lib/clonevirtualenv.py -> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/clonevirtualenv.py'
```

I tried skipping this step and tried the command `source .bashrc`
which again gave me an error saying "file not found":

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
```

(I checked my home directory but it was there). How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried sudo pip3 install virtualenvwrapper ?

Comment: @Zailef what will that do/how is it different from the one on the website? I will try anyways.

Comment: @Zailef it worked. No error. But the bashrc error remains

Comment: Nice one. It's because OSX has both Python 2 & 3. The pip for python 3 is aliased with pip3. As for the sudo, it needed superuser permission to install - hence the permission denied error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .bashrc try using .bash_profile, putting the same code as mentioned in the tutorial you linked inside. It's also quite likely that the location of your virtualenv wrapper won't be the same as the one in that tutorial, for instance, the entry for .bash_profile on my mac is:

```
#virtalenv
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```